# Double Parameter substitution to get variable value

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script that has to read a file(dataserver.properties) and alter some properties in it according to its type. I can have 10 different types in total (agis_int,agis_psr....). All of the types share the same number of variables (10 in total). 
this is an example of a data server.properties file

```
eg agis_int_dataserver.properties:
ODI_dataserver=< agis_int_dataserver>
ODI_user=< agis_int_host>
ODI_password=< agis_int_password>
ODI_hostname=< agis_int_hostname>
ODI_port=< agis_int_port>
```

I already have each of those properties loaded in a profile configuration file. Their names are [type]_property like below

```
.profile_topologies
export agis_int_dataserver=PAM_export
export agis_int_host=192.168.1.17
...
export agis_int_psr=SAM_im
export agis_int_psr=192.168.1.45
```

I know before hand the type name (one of the 10) and my goal is to kind of do a double parameter/variable substitution? I do not know if such thing exists but I wanted to avoid using a lot of if-cases.

what I wrongly came up with was

```
#the type parameter has the string name of the type (agis_int, agis_psr...)
 func( type) {

eg $type hold the string agis_int

cat $datasource_file | sed "s/<${type}_dataserver>/${${type}_dataserver}/g" >newdatasource.txt
(this one hold string name)<-------|                   |
                                                       |
(would hold variable value in the environment property)<-|
}
```

In the case above the first ${type}_dataserver expands to  "agis_int_dataserver" string corredtly.  The second case I would like it to expand to the variable value of "PAM_export" given by the variable agis_int_dataserver=PAM_export.

Is something like this possible, or is there a better way to do this?

I do not know if I made myself clear enough, it is hard to explain.

Comment: You *could* use indirection (`${!ref}`) but may want to have a look at dynamic arrays instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was such a quick answer. I was afraid I was not very clear with my question.
Because my scripts have to run on different shells I think I will try to use the answer that has " eval echo "\$${type}_dataserver"". At least this variation worked for me on bash sh and ash

Comment: also my question got closed and I think it cannot be indexed any more. I managed to find the answer in the original post.thanks!